# Is there a -more- efficient way to make excel return a value x if cell exceeds value y?

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

Sorry for maybe a lame posting, but I often encounter a need to return a pre-defined value x if cell exceeds y, but more efficient than below (due to often having long formulas)

Example below. I want cell to return 10 if

SUMIFS($AI$42:$AI$51;$AH$42:$AH$51;"<"&AH51)+1

is more than 10.

Is there a more efficient/elegant way than repeating this twice? i.e.

If((SUMIFS($AI$42:$AI$51;$AH$42:$AH$51;"<"&AH51)+1)>10;10;SUMIFS($AI$42:$AI$51;$AH$42:$AH$51;"<"&AH51)+1)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just put `sumifs` part into another cell, than use it in formula.

```
B1: =SUMIFS($AI$42:$AI$51;$AH$42:$AH$51;"<"&AH51)+1
RESULT: =If($B$1>10;10;$B$1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result can't be higher than 10 then I'd go with MIN formula:

```
MIN(10, SUMIFS($AI$42:$AI$51;$AH$42:$AH$51;"<"&AH51)+1)
```

No extra cells, shorter and cleaner.